# Flooding near side of porch?

Tags: porch

Every time when its a heavy rain fall, the one side and part of the front porch floods and over time it caused my porch to sink. The flood is usually 1 foot deep and it disappears minutes after it stop raining.  I decided to remove the wooden porch and replace it with concrete for better support. But sometimes I think I should do more than just replace the porch.  Is there any more solutions someone can give me that may stop the flooding. Do I need to build up area with dirt or rocks?[image]

Comment: Flooding is a VeryBadThing . It may wll lead to seepage into your basement (if you have one) or settling of your slab/foundation.  You probably should investigate a full drainage system: dry wells and French drains.